# Typographies spécifiques des sigles et acronymes

Tags: pluriel, typographie, abréviations

Y a-t-il des préconisations typographiques pour mettre au pluriel certains sigles et acronymes usuels ?

J'aurais tendance à écrire :

> Les *ADNs* des espèces de cette branche se différencient par…
>   … mais, il y dans l'*adn* de celle-là une particularité…

Si lire une étude sur le *sida* me semble naturel, écrire les *adns* m'interpelle car je ne connais pas d'*Acide DésoxyriboNucléique Singulier* ou *Spécial*.

Answer (score 10):

Un sigle (i. e. chaque lettre est prononcée séparément) comme *ADN* ou *TGV* s'écrit en général en lettres majuscules et reste invariable.

En revanche, il n'est pas rare que les acronymes, comme *sida* ou *radar*, soient assimilés à des mots normaux. Avec le temps ils acquièrent même les marques de pluriel et de genre.

Comment: Dans l'exemple http://www.proteigene.com/ADN.php est-ce une faute d'orthographe, ou un usage contemporain que l'on rencontre de plus en plus dans les journaux?

Comment: Je lis « purification de vos ADN », c'est là un usage tout à fait conventionnel des sigles.

Comment: je faisais référence au premier sous-titre : "Les produits que nous vous proposons pour la purification, la préparation, le stockage et l'analyse de vos ADNs". Il semble que les labos utilise

Comment: [Suite] ... utilisent **ADNs** : http://www.biofidal.fr/sequencage-adn.php ; § : *Marche ADN 2X*

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+ADN%2Cdes+ADNs%2C+des+TGV%2C+des+TGVs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: [Lacroux, Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/accolade-allemand.html#Acronyme) sur le sujet : « Les FAQ sont très bien, les Faqs posent d’inutiles problèmes — statut de la chose ? dénomination propre ? —, et les FAQs sont inadmissibles. Quant aux faqs, forme souhaitable pour un acronyme "lexicalisé" (une faq, des faqs comme un ovni, des ovnis), méritent-elles d’accéder déjà au panthéon lexical du "tout minuscule" et de l’accord en nombre ? Possible… À chacun de voir… Moi, je vote non… mais je ne ferai pas campagne… »

Comment: @Unfrancophone: En effet l'info vient de là, mais j'avais juste une flemme passagère pour retrouver l'extrait et le lien. Excellent choix pour l'extrait. Merci :-)

Comment: Et Grevisse, _le Bon Usage_, « Les sigles sont naturellement invariables lorsqu'ils sont en capitales : Les P.T.T. — Mais ils varient comme des noms ordinaires lorsqu'ils sont écrits comme des morts ordinaires: [exemples avec ovnis et radars] »

Comment: Je ne serais pas étonné de voir apparaitre le mot *adéhène* pour pouvoir l'accorder en nombre, après la *bédé* et le *cédérom*, je pense que les néologistes vont vit s'en *OQP*...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez pour le nGram que tu proposes : les résultats de la séquence "des ADNs" n'englobent-ils pas les résultats de l'autre ("des ADN") ? Si oui la comparaison est biaisée dès le départ...

Comment: @Romain: Non (c'est évident d'après les données et le biais irait de toutes façon dans le bon sens pour étayer ce que je soutiens.).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Au temps pour moi, ce n'est qu'un bête lapsus dans mon commentaire, je voulais bien entendu dire : les résultats de la séquence *des ADN* englobent les résultats de l'autre. Et ma remarque n'avait pour intention d'aller ni dans ton sens ni contre, je questionnais la pertinence du graphe, sans malice aucune. (en l'occurrence j'avais d'emblée *plussé* ta réponse très sensée.)